# Can't change the style of link

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-specificity

I'm very new to coding and I currently try to change the style of my html link.
I've nested my Picture, `<h1>` and `<p>` in a `<a href>` to make it all a link to the same destination, but now I can't change the style once it's a link. This is my HTML and CSS below.

as you can see in this link, the first  is not forestgreen https://aria-oslo-743-draft.superhi.com/blog.html

```css
body {
  font-family: Poly;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: #31fff511;
  color: #fa8601;
  margin: 80px auto 40px auto;
  width: 1120px;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

h1,
nav {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

section {
  margin: 80px 0 80px 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 2 / span 10;
  gap: 32px 32 px;
  text-align: center;
}

section h1 {
  color: forestgreen !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 32px;
}

section a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 32px;
  transition: color 0.5s;
}

header a {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 32px;
  transition: color 0.5s;
}

header a:hover {
  color: forestgreen;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

section img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <a href="blogpost.html">
    <img src="screenshot-2021-08-18-at-16.28.07.png">
    <h1> What in the JPEG 2</h1>
    <p> "Lorem ipsum" </p>
  </a>
</section>
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You say you "can't change the style once it's a link", but what does that mean? The h1 is colored `forestgreen`, so you've successfully changed that style. Please add more text explaining what you were expecting.

Comment: Sorry, this is my very first question asked here. But no it's still underlined and that purple color as you can see here: https://aria-oslo-743-draft.superhi.com/blog.html

Comment: Well, when I look at the code provided here, the `h1` is `forestgreen` in Chrome 92 on Windows 10. I'm not going to go to another site; questions should have a [mre] here on Stack Overflow that demonstrates the issue. Sounds like you have a bit more work to do on your simplified code.

Comment: Looking at your blog page, and comparing it to the snippet above, on your blog page, the HTML is not laid out the same as your code snippet. Looking at your blog page , your <h1> and <p> elements are outside of your <a href...> element.

Answer (score 1):

You need to address the dfferent states of that specific link using CSS selectors that are more specific than the general link rules, i.e. in your case `section a:link, section a:visited { ... }` and `section a:hover, section a:active  { ... }`

Answer (score -1):

The following is a snippet taken from https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links_colors.asp that explains how to update the colors of links. You also need to consider what color the link will be on mouse-over, once clicked, and once visited.

```
<style>
a:link {
  color: green;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: pink;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
  color: yellow;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>
```